# OpenGL shader node editor

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm working on a material editor very similar to Unreal or Unity and I got a stuck. I have no idea how to implement the most important piece of code: how to translate diagrams / nodes to glsl, so I have some questions:

- Is the vertex shader contains a constant number of attributes? For example: position, texture coordinates, normals, tangents, bitangens, and all light information, or is it depending on what nodes I have in the material, such as a normal map node.
- Do I have to change only fragment shader code or vertex/fragment shader code or geometry/fragment/vertex shader code after diagram has changed?

Comment: That depends a lot on the architecture of your program, the features you want to support, the layout of your data, and a lot of other things. In its current form, this question is way too broad for SO.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably first learn modern OpenGL, before setting on this sort of task. Here are brief answers to your question. For "in depth" info please grab some [good OpenGL book](https://web.archive.org/web/20150225192611/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html) and read it.

> Is the vertex shader contains a constant number of attributes?

Nope. It's user dependent. Based on your buffer configuration you may have `position`, `normals`,`uv` attrbutes - if you need to perform texture and normal mapping. In other cases, you may want to have just `position`, if all you need is to draw a geometry.The maximum allowed number of attributes is hardware dependent and you can query it using `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS`  token.

> Do I have to change only fragment shader code or vertex/fragment
>   shader code or geometry/fragment/vertex shader code after diagram has
>   changed?

It depends. There are special variables called [varyings](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29672/in-out-keywords-in-glsl). Those are used to pass data from one shader stage to another. For example here is a simple shader program source for drawing texture mapped geometry:

**Vertex shader:**

```
 #version 430 core
 layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
 layout(location = 1) in vec2 uv;
 out smooth vec2 v_uv;
 void main()
 {
   gl_Position = position;//we don't do any projection
   v_uv = uv; //send interpolated uvs to fragment shader
 }
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
 #version 430 core
 layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D tex;
 in smooth vec2 v_uv;
 out vec4 o_color;
 void main()
 {
    o_color= texture(tex,v_uv);
 }
```

As you can see, we pass `uv` attribute into fragment shader using `out` keyword which marks this variable as varying.In your case, if someone using your editor, adds varyings to a vertex shader,then they also have to add `in` version of that varying in the fragment shader as well. Hope I answered your questions.